# Implementing `downgrade_map` for `tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard`

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'm currently implementing an extension method `downgrade_map` (+ `try_downgrade_map`) on `tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard`, which goes from `RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>` to `RwLockReadGuard<'a, U>` with an `f: impl FnOnce(&T) -> &U`.

```rust
pub fn downgrade_map<'a, T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>(
    guard: tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>,
    f: impl FnOnce(&T) -> &U,
) -> tokio::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'a, U> {
    let value = f(&*guard) as *const U;
    let guard = tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard::downgrade(guard);
    // SAFETY: We only allow `&T -> &U`, not `&mut T -> &U`,
    //         which would allow breaking interior mutability,
    //         (e.g. `std::cell::Cell::get_mut`)
    tokio::sync::RwLockReadGuard::map(guard, |_| unsafe { &*value })
}
```

In [this tokio issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/3344), there are issues with using functions with signature `&mut T -> &mut U`, and that causing issues after downgrading.

In here, however, we only allow `&T -> &U`. Does that fix the soundness issue? Or are there any other consideration to have with this function that make it unsound?

Edit: In minimizing the example, I accidentally brought it to a point where unsafe wasn't needed anymore. What I was originally trying to implement `try_downgrade_map` does require unsafe though:

```rust
fn try_downgrade_map<'a, T, U>(
    guard: tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>,
    f: impl FnOnce(&T) -> Option<&U>,
) -> Result<tokio::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'a, U>, tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard<'a, T>> {
    let value = match f(&*this) {
        Some(value) => value as *const U,
        None => return Err(this),
    };
    let guard = tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard::downgrade(this);
    let guard = tokio::sync::RwLockReadGuard::map(guard, |_| unsafe { &*value });
    Ok(guard)
}
```

This can't be implemented in safe code because I want to ensure that downgrading only happens if `f` returns `None` (and I can't call `f` twice). My original code where I use it is something like this:

```rust
pub async fn foo(lock: RwLock<T>) {
    // Check with a read lock
    if let Ok(value) = RwLockReadGuard::try_map(lock.read().await, |value| value.try_get()) {
        return value;
    }

    // Else "upgrade" and check if it was changed in the meantime
    let guard = lock.write().await;
    if let Ok(value) = RwLockWriteGuard::try_downgrade_map(guard, |value| value.try_get()) {
        return value;
    }

    // Use `guard` mutably
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It feels like it is sound, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue in the `tokio` issue tracker, and/or discuss this in their discord. This sounds like a situation that shouldn't require `unsafe`, so it might be worth adding such a function in their official API.

Comment: There might be soundness issues around thin/fat pointers, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question *should* be sound, but versions of these methods have been added to `tokio 1.27.0` in [this PR](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/5527).

Now you can just use them and the `foo` function in the question works as-is.